# Changing where some data goes from a PHP function to a database

Tags: php, sql

A developer built this function for me and I'd like a very basic change. I'm pretty slow when it comes to programming and would appreciate someone helping me out.

The function currently inserts data into a table called download. I'd like some of that data to be inserted into a table called tax instead.

This is the current function:

```
function createDownloadLink($conn,$countryid,$buyerCountry='',$buyerCurrency='',$buyerCost='')
{

try{

$sql=' INSERT INTO `download` (`downloadcount` ,`downloadstring` , `downloadcountryid`, `startdownloadtime`, `enddownloadtime`,`buyerCountry`,`buyerCurrency`,`buyerCost`) VALUES ( "0" , "'.time().'" , "'. $countryid .'", NOW(), NOW() + INTERVAL 72 HOUR,"'.$buyerCountry.'","'.$buyerCurrency.'","'.$buyerCost.'");';
//$rs=$conn->query($sql);
mysqli_query($conn , $sql) or die("Error" . mysqli_error($conn));

$last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);

echo $last_id;

$downloadstring = generateDownloadString($last_id);

$sql='UPDATE `download` SET `downloadstring` = "'. $downloadstring . '" WHERE `download`.`downloadid` = "' . $last_id . '";';
$rs=$conn->query($sql);

return $downloadstring;
}catch(Exception $e) {
//return 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
}

}
```

I'd like the data from the variables buyerCountry, buyerCurrency and buyerCost to go into the tax table. Ideally this would still be part of one function, as it's called in another file.

Comment: Simply replicate the `$sql=' INSERT INTO `download`` etc line and the query after it and change the name of the table, columns and variables as desired.

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to duplicate the $sql='INSER... line and modify the table name and columns to insert into tax table. I have modified your code to do what you ask. Just copy and paste:

function createDownloadLink($conn,$countryid,$buyerCountry='',$buyerCurrency='',$buyerCost='') {

```
try{
    $sql=' INSERT INTO `download` (`downloadcount` ,`downloadstring` , `downloadcountryid`, `startdownloadtime`, `enddownloadtime`,`buyerCountry`,`buyerCurrency`,`buyerCost`) VALUES ( "0" , "'.time().'" , "'. $countryid .'", NOW(), NOW() + INTERVAL 72 HOUR,"'.$buyerCountry.'","'.$buyerCurrency.'","'.$buyerCost.'");';
    //$rs=$conn->query($sql);
    mysqli_query($conn , $sql) or die("Error" . mysqli_error($conn));

    //insert into tax table
    $sql_insert_tax=' INSERT INTO `tax` (`buyerCountry`,`buyerCurrency`,`buyerCost`) VALUES ("'.$buyerCountry.'","'.$buyerCurrency.'","'.$buyerCost.'");';
    mysqli_query($conn , $sql_insert_tax) or die("Error" . mysqli_error($conn));


    $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);

    echo $last_id;

    $downloadstring = generateDownloadString($last_id);

    $sql='UPDATE `download` SET `downloadstring` = "'. $downloadstring . '" WHERE `download`.`downloadid` = "' . $last_id . '";';
    $rs=$conn->query($sql);

    return $downloadstring;

}catch(Exception $e) {
    //return 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
}
```

}

Comment: That showed the error. I do appreciate the help, but I think you've made it attempt to insert the things I wanted to go only into the tax table go into both. My attempt to remove what I think shouldn't be there gave me the same error.